# Django - Inline Forms and Foreign Keys

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have an app that allows a user to create an estimate for a project. The estimate has the basic client information (name, address, phone number, etc.) and a custom Primary Key value that I generate. Now, I also have two other models for listing estimated products and labour needed for the job. These two models are linked to the "main" estimate model with a Foreign Key. For these two models I was going to use inline formsets since they, by default, link to another record via a foreign key.

I'm wondering if it is possible to create the main estimate (the basic data) record *at the same time* as the two inline forms? It seems like it wouldn't work (well, I'm having trouble making it work) since the foreign key that the two inline formsets are linked to doesn't exist yet because it is also *just* being created.

Would it be better to make this a two step process: Step 1) Create & save basic data (thereby creating the primary key that can be linked to) Step 2) Add product and labour records linking them by the foreign key of the main record. It just seems that this would be a poor UI design (having two steps).

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to create the main estimate (the basic data) record at the same time as the two inline forms?

This is, in fact, the way the admin (`django.contrib.admin`) does it for an inline form.

If you don't feel like diving into that code, you could try to use [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) to bundle all the database changes together, so you can roll them all back if needed. This assumes your back-end database supports transactions, of course.